# Disable line buffering in TTY but keep Ctrl+D enabled

Tags: linux, tty

By default a TTY is in canonical mode, meaning that it buffers received data until it gets end-of-line or end-of-file (by default Ctrl+D). However, the buffer is only 4096 bytes in size, so if I am sending lots of data to a process through a TTY, I am forced to write chunks of < 4096 bytes followed by Ctrl+D. This slows down my program.

I can disable the line buffering by setting the TTY to raw mode, but in raw mode it no longer responds to end-of-file, but directly sends my Ctrl+D to the remote process, which treats it as any other byte. So I have no way of indicating to the process that the data stream has concluded.

I know that the TTY has a setting where even in raw mode it responds to the interrupt character (Ctrl+C). This is not suitable because if I send a Ctrl+C, the remote process may get a SIGINT and die before processing all of the data that came before.

What I really want is for the TTY to not buffer data but send it directly to the process, and once I send a Ctrl+D, I want it to send EOF to process. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Comment: I think it is developing question. My understanding is that Surya is developing an application and the question is how to set a suitable buffering policy. O do not know answer but I guess it can be achieved via combination of `setbuf()` and `tcsetattr()`. I think it is a valid question.

Comment: When talking to another program, you'd usually be writing through a pipe, not through a TTY. End-of-data is indicated simply by closing the output stream.

Comment: TTY and pipe should accept arbitrary amounts of data. If buffers get full, the sending program is (usually) set on interruptible wait, allowing the reading program time to drain the buffer, which puts the sending program back into running state.